# Qt - calling mappedReduced

Tags: qt, concurrency

I was trying to use QtConcurrent:mappedReduced, but it was not with the simplicity of the documentation description.I'm getting 4 errors with this code:

**I'm using Qt 5.9.1 with MSVC-2015**

```
//.......................
QMap<QString,QString> TesseractAPI::analyze(QStringList singleData);

void joinMaps(QMap<QString,QString> map, const QMap<QString,QString> partial);
//.............
QMap<QString, QString> TesseractAPI::analyzeAll(QList<QStringList> data){

    /*QFuture< QMap<QString,QString> > res*/;
    QFuture< QMap<QString,QString> > res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(data, TesseractAPI::analyze, joinMaps); // I tried adding '&' before the functors
    res.waitForFinished();
    qDebug()<<res.result();
    return res.result();

}
```

The compiler errors:

```
 C2780: 'QFuture<QtPrivate::ReduceResultType<ReduceFunctor>::ResultType> QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided

 C2780: 'QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided

 C2780: 'QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided

 C2783: 'QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(const Sequence &,MapFunctor,ReduceFunctor,QtConcurrent::ReduceOptions)': could not deduce template argument for 'ResultType'
```

I tried to change data types, I also followed examples in the documentation which compile fines, but I couldn't find where the problem persist in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a lot of &'s.
First you should pass the data to `analyzeAll()` via const ref, not copy:

```
 QMap<QString, QString> TesseractAPI::analyzeAll(const QList<QStringList>& data){
```

Next, you should pass the item to the mapping function via const ref, not copy. Since it's a class member function it also needs to be static, otherwise you would have to know which object to call it on, but there's no such `mappedReduced()` overload:

```
static QMap<QString,QString> TesseractAPI::analyze(const QStringList& singleData);
```

Next, the first parameter of the reduce function needs to be a reference, otherwise you'd be modifying a local copy, which would be useless. The thing you are reducing should also be passed via const ref, to avoid unnecessary copy:

```
void joinMaps(QMap<QString,QString>& map, const QMap<QString,QString>& partial);
```

Now it should work. For the sake of stating your intent it's also nice to explicitly add & to the function pointers, so there's no confusion what they are:

```
QFuture< QMap<QString,QString> > res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(data, &TesseractAPI::analyze, &joinMaps);
```

Comment: I cannot turn 'analyze' to  static since it needs to access private member variables

Comment: Pointers to members are only supported for the container elements class, i.e. members of QStringList in this case. Since you want an unrelated function of an unrelated object you need to wrap it into a functor object as described here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html#using-function-objects